# Centering a text in svg not working correctly

Tags: html, css, svg, center

I'm having trouble centering a text inside a rectangle in svg. I've followed advice to use dominant baseline, but the text appears a few pixels off, and I'd like to understand where this is coming from.

Below is a react snippet of 2 side by side labels, one using svg and the other using the flexbox model for reference.

What is the cause for the difference we see? How can I achieve the same behavior as flexbox align items and justify content in svg?

```
const TestSvg = () => {
    const x = 10;
    const width = 52.35581970214844 ;
    const y = 0;
    const height = 14;

    const svg = (
        <svg width={'65px'} height={'30px'}>
            <g width={width} height={height}>
                <rect x={x} y={y} width={width} height={height} rx={'3px'} fill={'red'}/>
                <text
                    x={x + width / 2} y={ y + height / 2}
                    style={{
                        fontSize: '11px',
                        fontWeight: 700,
                        fill: '#fff',
                        textAnchor: 'middle',
                        dominantBaseline: 'middle'
                    }}>{'BLA'}</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    )

    const flex = (
        <div>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: '3px', width: width}}>
            <div style={{
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontWeight: 700,
                color: '#fff',
                textAnchor: 'middle',
                dominantBaseline: 'middle'
            }}>{'BLA'}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            {svg}
            {flex}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please post the resultant output SVG, or a working [mcve]. So we don't have to build a web app ourselves just to see your code running.

Comment: Using textAnchor: 'middle', dominantBaseline: 'middle' should do the trick. Can you inspect the result that React returns and maybe post it here as suggested by @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 0):

I cannot account for the difference that you report.

I made a vanilla version of your code and removed the `<g>`. `<text>` needs to be placed in the middle (50% 50%). In SVG it is often easier to have position, size etc. relative.

```css
:root {
  --width: 100%;
  --height: 100%;
}

svg>rect {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  rx: 3px;
  fill: red;
}

div#s1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 65px;
}

svg>text,
div#s1>div {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  fill: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <svg width="65px" height="30px">
      <rect x="0" y="0" />
      <text x="50%" y="50%">BLA</text>
  </svg>
  <div id="s1">
    <div>BLA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```